# Private IP availability

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, ip

Is the Private IP included in the Corporate edition?

Shall I ask for the activation of this IP to the Salesforce Account Representative or to Salesforce Support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [this comparison sheet](https://brandcdn.exacttarget.com/sites/exacttarget/files/editions_comparison_data_sheet_-_marketing_cloud_v2.pdf), you get a private IP in any edition other than Basic. This also comes with a Sender Authentication Package (SAP).

SAP includes a Private Domain (tied to link and image wrapping), a Dedicated IP, Reply Mail Management, and Authentication (SPF, Sender ID, DKIM, and Domain Keys).

Once you have decided on your domain for the SAP, you should fill out the SAP Request form, and it will be configured with your private IP address.

Even though the SAP consists of multiple components, a.o. a private IP address, you can't use this IP address without configuring the SAP. Which leaves you with two options: configure the SAP including the private IP, or purchase a separate private IP. Moving forward with a private IP but without a configured SAP is not recommended, as your links will not be branded and your sender domain not properly authenticated.

Also, just because you CAN configure a private IP, it is not necessarilly a good idea. The bare minumum email volume for a private IP is at least 100.000 emails per month, preferably above 250.000.

Regardless, you should reach out to support and ask for them to confirm there is an SAP/Private IP available, assist you in configuring it, or direct you to your account executive in order to purchase either of these two.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. So, if I don't want to buy SAP, who should I contact in order to have the Private IP configured?

Comment: @Gio I have provided additional clarification in my answer above. I really can't help you more specifically with the minimal information you have provided in your question.

Comment: Many thanks, @Lukas Lunow. The document you shared suggests that the Corporate edition has already included SAP with no additional costs, is it correct? Thank you

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @Gio - please accept my answer if it has been helpful!